Macでコードを書いているときに英数キーやかなキー（スペースキーの両隣）を押すと、 カーソルがスクリプトからRコンソールに自動的に移ってしまい困っています。
MacでRのプログランミング中、
英数キーやかなキー（スペースキーの両隣）を押すと、
カーソルがスクリプトからRコンソールに自動的に移ってしまいます。
環境はRstudioではなく生のRです。
以前はそのような挙動はなかったのですが、
ここ最近になっての話です。
PCの環境設定も確認してみたのですが、思い当たる節がありませんでした。
Googleで調べてみたり、チャットGPTに尋ねてみても解決せず、
非常に困っています。
PCのシステム設定より、キーボードの設定をデフォルトに直してみましたが無理でした。
どなたか解決策をご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。
